# Flutter how to get Stripe checkout_session url

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the url from checkout_session in `Firestore` but I got this error even if the url is in Firestore:

```
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field "url" does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
```

If I click once this error appears and the Checkout screen isn't launch, when I click for the second time the Checkout screen is launch.

What am I missing.

Here is the code

```
class PremiumCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String premiumLogo;
  final String premiumTypeTitle;
  final String premiumPrice;
  final String premiumReductionText;
  final Color color1;
  final Color color2;
  final Color color3;
  final MembershipViewModel viewModel;
  final String amount;
  final String membershipPriceId;
  final FireStoreUser fireStoreUser;

  const PremiumCardWidget({super.key, required this.premiumLogo,
    required this.premiumTypeTitle, required this.premiumPrice,
    required this.premiumReductionText, required this.color1,
    required this.color2, required this.color3, required this.viewModel,
    required this.amount, required this.membershipPriceId,
    required this.fireStoreUser,});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    return PaddingWidget(
      widget: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
          ),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(
              ValueManager.v10,
            ),
          ),
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          color1,
          color2,
          color3,
        ],
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      ),
    ),
    child: Card(
      elevation: ValueManager.v4,
      color: Colors.black,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(
          color: ColorManager.black,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          ValueManager.v10,
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: ValueManager.v30,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Logo & title ------------------------------------------------
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  premiumLogo,
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: ValueManager.v20,
                ),
                Text(
                  premiumTypeTitle,
                  style: getBoldStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: ColorManager.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // Price -------------------------------------------------------
            Text(
              premiumPrice,
              style: getBoldStyle(
                fontSize: 26,
                color: ColorManager.white,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: ValueManager.v20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                // Check icon ----------------------------------------------
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    GradientIconWidget(
                      icon: Icons.done,
                      size: ValueManager.v24,
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [
                          color1,
                          color2,
                          color3,
                        ],
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: ValueManager.v10,
                    ),
                    GradientIconWidget(
                      icon: Icons.done,
                      size: ValueManager.v24,
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [
                          color1,
                          color2,
                          color3,
                        ],
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                // Text
                const SizedBox(
                  width: ValueManager.v20,
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      premiumReductionText,
                      style: getRegularStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: ColorManager.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: ValueManager.v20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      StringManager.premiumCancel,
                      style: getRegularStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: ColorManager.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: ValueManager.v20,
            ),
            // Button ------------------------------------------------------
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                DocumentReference documentReference = await _firestore
                    .collection("users")
                    .doc(fireStoreUser.uid)
                    .collection("checkout_sessions")
                    .add({
                  "price": membershipPriceId,
                  "success_url": "https://checkout.stripe.com/success",
                  "cancel_url": "https://checkout.stripe.com/cancel",
                });

                documentReference.snapshots().listen((ds) async {
                  if(ds.exists) {
                    var url = ds.get("url"); <----------------------- Error seems to be here

                    var res = await Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => CheckoutScreen(url: url),
                      ),
                    );

                    if(res == "success") {
                      // Payment complete
                      logger.i("Payment completed");
                    }
                    else {
                      // Payment failed
                      logger.w("Payment failed");
                    }
                  }
                });
              },
              child: SizedBox(
                height: ValueManager.v40,
                child: GradientButtonWidget(
                  buttonTitle: StringManager.membershipButtonTitle,
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      color1,
                      color2,
                      color3,
                    ],
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // Cancel text -------------------------------------------------
            const SizedBox(
              height: ValueManager.v40,
            ),
            Text(
              StringManager.autoRenewal,
              style: getRegularStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: ColorManager.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: I'm not a Flutter expert so can't give too much advice on the actual code, but it sounds like you are trying to access the CheckoutSession.url before it exists.  Is it possible you need to await an asynchronous operation before you attempt to access the property?  Try logging what the value of the Session variable is before you access the URL property to check.  I would provide a more concise snippet of code that shows you fetching and accessing the session as well.

Comment: you need to change url with success_url

Comment: @RyanM yes that what I'm trying, even with `var url = await ds.get("url");` it doesn't works. First there is only `price`, `success_url`, `cancel_url` and then when user click on the button `client`, `created`, `mode`, `sessionId` & `url` are automatically added When I put a DateTime.now in log I see that the fields are added at an hour X & I try to get them at the same X hour that's surely the problem but don't know how to solve it. @Anas Nadeem it's not that I'm trying to get this field so no.